# Nginx + phpFPM: PATH_INFO always empty

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I configured nginx stable (1.4.4) + PHP (using FastCGI, php-fpm) on Debian. That works fine:

```
     location ~* ^/~(.+?)(/.*\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        autoindex on;
     }
```

I use the PATH_INFO variable, therefore I added the following line to fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
```

And in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0
```

I think that should work, but when I print out all server variables, PATH_INFO is always empty:

```
    array (
  'USER' => 'www-data',
  'HOME' => '/var/www',
  'FCGI_ROLE' => 'RESPONDER',
  'QUERY_STRING' => '',
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'CONTENT_TYPE' => '',
  'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/usr/share/nginx/html/srv_var.php',
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/srv_var.php',
  'PATH_INFO' => '',
  'REQUEST_URI' => '/srv_var.php',
  'DOCUMENT_URI' => '/srv_var.php',
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/usr/share/nginx/html',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'nginx/1.4.4',
  .....
)
```

I can not figure where the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: did you find solution to this ?

Comment: Hi , probably http request does not contain script name like index.php ?  Can you show a request to your script ?

Comment: what's your url?

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled across a solution to this. The `$fastcgi_path_info` var works together with `$fastcgi_split_path_info`, and needs to be set within the location block. Here's what worked in our environment:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    root /var/www/jurism-php;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

There is also an example in the [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) under `fastcgi_split_path_info`.

(... which I now see matches more than one post above. Possibly the PATH_INFO line needs to be set after the include statement, to avoid clobbering the value.)

Answer (score 6):

## Debug with PHP

First of all, in modern PHP, the `PATH_INFO` is stored in the `$_SERVER` array. Try:

```
echo "called SCRIPT_NAME: {$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']} with PATH_INFO: {$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']}";
```

In any case `phpinfo()` comes to the rescue to help find a lot of the internal php information, like variables and configurations.

## Nginx config

As for the NginX config most of it is already explained in the other posts. So this here is a summary and a closer look at the details and the why of the following sample location block:

```
location /main.php {
  # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path_info
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

  # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
  try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

  # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
  # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
  set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

  # set the standard fcgi paramters
  include fastcgi.conf;

  # pass the request to the socket
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

## Explanation line-by-line

The `fastcgi_split_path_info` splits your location between `SCRIPT_NAME` and `PATH_INFO`.

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
```

The expression in the **first** parentheses of the regular-expression extracts the `SCRIPT_NAME`, while the **second** extracts the `PATH_INFO`.

---

#### Recap on regular-expressions

- The first regex group, `(.+?\.php)`, expects any character (the dot `.`), at least once or more than once (the plus `+`). with a trailing `.php`. The dot in `.php` is escaped to `\.php` so it's taken literally not as "any character".
  The questionmark `?` makes the plus lazy (`+?`) so the evaluation stops at the first `.php` suffix.

  - **E.g.** - `/some.php/next.php/path-info` is evaluated to a `SCRIPT_NAME` of `/some.php` with a `PATH_INFO` of `/next.php/path-info`; beware, not to a `SCRIPT_NAME` of `/some.php/next.php` with a `PATH_INFO` of `/path-info`.
- The second regexp group, `(/.*)`, basically takes everything that start with a slash as `PATH_INFO`.
- The leading `^` and trailing `$` bind the expressions to the start and end of the line.

---

The next line checks that the extracted script really does exist as a file:

```
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
```

Otherwise it returns a `404` error. This prevents giving non-existing files to the PHP processor, however has the bad habit of resetting the `$fastcgi_path_info` variable (see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321).
One workaround is to store `$fastcgi_path_info` in `$path_info` and set the FCGI param to the stored `$path_info`. This is done by the next two lines:

```
# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
```

The other FCGI parameters are then set within the include of `fastcgi.conf`. This file, that's sometimes also named `fastcgi_params` should be provided by your distribution.

```
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Then finally pass the request to your current PHP instance socket (here PHP 7.4):

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

---

## Conclusion

Now remember that **all of this happens only, if the surrounding location block is hit**. The above example is a prefix location, meaning that every location is matched, that starts with the prefix `/main.php`. This would be a typical configuration for a routed PHP application that has only one central file named `main.php`. To catch all `.php` files a regex has to be used, which could be as simple as `^.+?\.php(/|$)`. The `(/|$)` after the `.php` means that there's either a slash (and more characters) or nothing after the `.php` part of the location. Subdirectories are also allowed, so the expression matches basically every location that somewhere contains the string `.php`, as long as it's either at the end or followed by a slash.

```
location ~ ^.+?\.php(/|$) {
  #...
}
```

As the location is only the guard that allows entering the following block, the final PHP filename and path-info are still split as described above. If the resulting filename does not exist a 404 is returned.

This is just a simple configuration. Of course there's a myriad of possibilities to configure the location regex, to suit the needs of your specific application. To go into all that details would be a small book.

Answer (score 5):

My working configuration is as follows:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)($|/.*);
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;  
    include fastcgi_params;    
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample

http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321

Comment: I added these two lines to the fastcgi_param file, but it doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For people getting here, reading things..

The problem seems to be that the regular expression (regex) in

```
location ~* ^/~(.+?)(/.*\.php)$ {
```

will never match a uri that does not end on .php, so the other regex will never "catch" anything in the last capturing group.

```
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
```

So changing that first regex to something like the following will "fix" that.

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it might be useful to someone.

I used the variable REQUEST_URI instead of PATH_INFO. Looks like it contains the same value as PATH_INFO is supposed to have.

Comment: no it doesn't. according to [php.org](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) PATH_INFO is `pathname information trailing the actual script filename but preceding the query string` and REQUEST_URI is full uri (with file name and query string)

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info

```
location ~ .+\.php {
    fastcgi_pass    {your_php_fpm_sock_or_server};

    # Some old (custom) frameworks use "PATH_INFO" for routing, requiring the following 2 settings. (e.g. index.php/Home/index)
    fastcgi_split_path_info             ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is what i got. and it works like a charm.

- nginx 1.10.1
- php 5.6.24

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/

Comment: Answers should not just link to external resources. A description or quote of the solution to the question should be included inside the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have come across this issue but my scenario is slightly different as I use `try_files` in my directive. Here is my config along with technical explanations:

This is what my `location` block looks like

```
location / {
    include         php-fpm.conf;
    try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
}
```

and `php-fpm.conf`

```
fastcgi_pass                127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index               index.php;
fastcgi_split_path_info     ^(.+?\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_param               PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
set $path_info              $fastcgi_path_info;
include                     fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_param               PATH_INFO $path_info;
```

Two special notices here:

- I installed `nginx` via `brew` and it did **not** contain `PATH_INFO` param so I had to add it manually (taken from [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/))

```
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_path_info;
```

- using `try_files` is a special case ([source](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321))

```
The ​try_files directive changes URI of a request to the one matched on the file system, and subsequent attempt to split the URI into $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path_info results in empty path info - as there is no path info in the URI after try_files.
```

- so what we do is save `INFO_PATH` to a temporary variable and then set `INFO_PATH` using that temporary variable